# How to get "controller support" and "number of player" badges for a macOS game in the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, game-center, tvos

Consider "The Last Campfire" (awesome game BTW):

[image: The Last Campfire]

Notice the "*Controller / Supported*" and "*Players / 1 Single*" badges.

### Game Controller Capability

To get the controller's badge in iOS and tvOS, I know we should add the "Game Controllers capability" under "**Signing & Capabilities**" [as described here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=hk2u622s).

However there's no such capability in a macOS target.

These are the available macOS capabilities in Xcode 12.2 (beta 3):

[image: macOS capabilities]

So yeah, no Game Controllers there as you can see and I'm clueless on how to display that capability for a macOS game.

### Number of Players Capability

For the second capability (number of players) I have absolutely no clue how to get that for either iOS, tvOS or macOS.
¯_(ツ)_/¯

Is it something I should add into the PLIST, or is it maybe a metadata in the App Store Connect?

Comment: That seems to be an Apple Arcade specific feature. I don’t see it in any game outside Apple Arcade.

Comment: For the game controller part, is your macOS deployment target version set to macOS 11.0+?

Comment: @MarcoBoerner Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And I assume you also tried adding GCSupportsControllerUserInteraction = true manually to the PLIST?

Comment: And the GCSupportedGameControllers dictionary? : )

Comment: Yes and yes. No dice. Maybe it's like @EmilioPelaez mentioned. Maybe this is for Apple Arcade games only. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯